# build two versions of RPMs in one rpm build

Tags: rpmbuild, rpm-spec

what I'm trying to do is to create two RPMs with two versions under one rpmbuild. I'm using the same source code to build those RPMs but the %post section in spec file behaves differently between two versions.

I managed to build two RPMs with different versions and packages names by using subpackage, but I do want two RPMs to have the same name.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean `rpmbuild ... package1.spec package2.spec`?

Answer (score 0):

They can't have the same name. You can have everything the same except the `%post` - but they need different names, since `rpmbuild` will only drop the output files in one place.